# How do I handle the youtube data api error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, youtube-data-api

I have been trying to access the Youtube data API v3 for my personal project, I have also generated the API key from the Google API console. Here is the code to fetch the API:

```
const API_KEY = '....-3jNA';
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  const [darkmode, setDarkmode] = useState(false);

  const menuIconSelect = () => {
    setClicked(!clicked);
  };

  const toggleChecked = () => {
    setDarkmode((prev) => !prev);
  };

  const params = new URLSearchParams({
    part: 'snippet',
    maxResults: 10,
    key: API_KEY  
  })


  const handleFormSubmit = async (searchterm) => {
    fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=${searchterm}${ params.toString()}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
  };
```

I get a response from the API, here is the response

```
 {kind: "youtube#searchListResponse", etag: "gHBbZNcsJQ6_Wo887P1ISCBPRF4", nextPageToken: "CAoQAA", regionCode: "IN", pageInfo: {…}, …}
 etag: "gHBbZNcsJQ6_Wo887P1ISCBPRF4"
 items: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 kind: "youtube#searchListResponse"
 nextPageToken: "CAoQAA"
 pageInfo: {totalResults: 368, resultsPerPage: 10}
 regionCode: "IN"
 __proto__: Object
```

But I keep getting these errors
[image: But I keep getting these errors]

Comment: I don't think they are caused by your code. Check the stack of those errors.

Comment: Please obey to SO guidelines: error messages produced by programs should be posted in plain text (eventually, [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)).

Comment: @prem kulkarni: I concur with CherryDT: those errors do not originate from YouTube Data API.

Comment: I am also not getting some data like thumbnails and stuff from the response ....do you think these errors might be the reason?

Comment: @prem kulkarni: The [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint does not provide *thumbnails*, but a so-called [Search resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource). Note that the response is plain JSON text.